# Delayed text display in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This sort of works, as it displays the text character by character, but very rapidly. I haven't figured out a way to get a control to make it go slower though. Any ideas would be appreciated!

The idea is I want the text to display in the text box like someone is typing it.

`ltr` is a private int declared outside the method. There's more to the code but I believe this is the most important part. If you want to see all of it I'll gladly show.

```
IEnumerator FillText()
{
    text.text = intro.Substring(0, ltr);
    if (ltr < intro.Length) { ltr++; }
    if (ltr == intro.Length) { StopCoroutine("FillText"); }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
}
```

Comment: How/where you call FillText?

Comment: Wait for more than 0.2 of a second?

Comment: waiting in the end of a routine will not really delay anything ... is there some loop around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class that does what you would like to achieve
Just drop this component on a gameObject and call it's `StartTypeWriterOnText` pass a Text component, a string to display on that text component, and an optional float value that will tell the effect how much to wait between characters.

```
public class TypeWriterTest : Monobehaviour
{
    WaitForSeconds _delayBetweenCharactersYieldInstruction;

    public void StartTypeWriterOnText(Text textComponent, string stringToDisplay, float delayBetweenCharacters = 0.2f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(TypeWriterCoroutine(textComponent, stringToDisplay,  float delayBetweenCharacters));
    }
    
    IEnumerator TypeWriterCoroutine(Text textComponent, string stringToDisplay, float delayBetweenCharacters)
    {
        // Cache the yield instruction for GC optimization
        _delayBetweenCharactersYieldInstruction = new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenCharacters);
        // Iterating(looping) through the string's characters
        for(int i = 0; i < stringToDisplay.Length; i++)
        {
            // Retrieves part of the text from string[0] to string[i]
            textComponent.text = stringToDisplay.Substring(0, i);
            // We wait x seconds between characters before displaying them
            yield return _delayBetweenCharactersYieldInstruction;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I'd vote it up if I could but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Glad i could help :)